# Pros and Cons of Server Virtualization - Comparison Between Windows Guest and Linux Guest

Tags: virtualization

I work in a hybrid windows/linux workplace.  I currently need to acquire a new server in the office and have decided that virtualization on the server would be the best option.  I want to know the pros and cons of the following setups:

Windows Hosting a Guest Linux Server

Linux Hosting a Guest Windows Server

Unfortunately, the purchase of two separate servers for each operating system is not within the budget.  Licensing costs are a concern and I would like to minimize them if possible by using open source as much as possible.

What are the Pro's/Con's/Options of each?  Anyone currently using a similar setup?

Additionally, any best practices and other options are welcome as well!

** Update **
It seems that I was a little out of touch with current virtualization options.  I have selected the best answer for others considering the path I was originally going to take.

Comment: A few years too late...

Comment: I don't know why this was closed.  There are definite pros and cons to each setup.  My question does not ask which is better or which should be chosen.  I am concerned with practical issues that may occur.

Comment: None of the above.  Host both Windows and Linux on a [type 1 hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor).  E.G **Vmware ESXi**, Xen, KVM, Hyper-V.

Comment: Read our FAQ and then you'd know, it's also a VERY out of date question, virtualisation has been the norm for a very long time. By the way unless you're very tied to a Windows-only management toolset the answer is almost always to use VMWare's vSphere/ESXi suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know the pros and cons of the following setups:
>
> Windows Hosting a Guest Linux Server
>
> Linux Hosting a Guest Windows Server

Why are these the only options? The *best* option would be to use a bare-metal hypervisor like VMWare ESXi or Hyper-V Server to make **both** OSes guests instead of having one host virtualizing a guest and running other services. This is really the way that you should set this up.

Comment: Thank You. I will look into these options.  Licensing costs are going to be a major determining factor.  I would prefer to spend the additional money on hardware.

Comment: @semyazza Both of those solutions can be free.

Comment: @semyazza Both Hyper-V Server and ESXi are free. SCVMM - the management tool for Hyper-V and vCenter - the management tool for ESXI both cost money, but neither are necessary in a 1 machine setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It has been years since I looked at virtualization options and I just inherited an IT mess that can be cleaned up with this type of solution.  Thanks!